# How can I write a command into a subprocess?

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, netcat, telnet

Currently, I am working on a project where I use telnet to netcat to send an email message within my university.

I am trying to make the process automated but my script can't seem to enter in any commands after I connect to the mail server (MX). Here is what I have so far.

```
import subprocess
status = subprocess.Popen('nc mx0a-00164701.pphosted.com 25', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = status.communicate(input=b'helo Bob')
```

But the `helo Bob` command never gets read and the rest of my script never gets executed. When I look at the result in my terminal, I get a 220 connection success message for the mx server connection.

Comment: Typically it would be `HELO bob.example.org\r\n`, and `EHLO` did replace `HELO` some number of years ago. It might be simpler to find code that already implements a SMTP client (or ESMTP client...).

Comment: It would be a good thing to tag the question with the language your code example is in (looks like python?)  Do your `b'...'` strings send a carriage return / line feed pair of characters as specified in the SMTP prototol RFCs?  A lack of expected command termination characters could prevent the SMTP server from knowing when your command is complete and it's safe to parse it and respond.

Comment: the socket api isn't too hard, and is a good fit if all you are doing is running nc.  Here is a link which has a simple client example how to send and receive https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example